# How do I delete my last panel?

Tags: gnome-panel

The last panel on gnome is being a pain to delete. I've tried the gconfig editor or whatever and going to desktop -> sessions and deleting the required applet text.

Then when I kill it through the task manager it still just reopens itself, being a pain.

Is there any other way to delete the last gnome panel? I don't want any of them at the moment, just my dock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open gconf-editor, in desktop/gnome/session/required_components change the panel value from gnome-panel to your dock of choice.

Restart your session and your dock will be auto-started by gnome and re-spawned if needed.

Note that you will lose some keyboard shortcuts like ALT+F2 if you remove your last panel, if you need them you should just hide it.

[image]

Comment: Ah okay. The previous set of directions I saw didn't say anything about restarting the session, just killing the gnome-panel. Is there any way to add the ALT+F2 window to a launcher on Avant? Like what command would launch that?

Comment: I suspect that there is no command. It's just a gnome-panel function. So this is why you lose it. But I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 1):

I did that deleting the content of the panel property.
Open gconf-editor and then go to desktop->session->required_components.
Edit the panel property and delete the content. Next time you login gnome-panel won't be loaded.

To undo just set the property back.